# Rudin Theorem 1.35 - Cauchy Schwarz Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Any motivation for the sum that Rudin considers in his proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

> **Theorem 1.35** If $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1, ..., b_n$ are complex numbers, then
>
> $$\Biggl\vert\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\overline{b_j}\Biggr\vert^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2.$$

For the proof, he considers this sum to kick it off:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \vert Ba_j - Cb_j\vert, \text{ where } B = \sum_{j=1}^n \vert b_j \vert^2 \text{ and } C = \sum_{j=1}^na_j\overline{b_j}.$$

I don't see where it comes from. Any help?

Thank-you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He does it because **it works**. Essentially, as you see, $$\sum_{j=1}^n |Ba_j-Cb_j|^{2}$$ is always **greater or equal to zero**. He then shows that $$\tag 1 \sum_{j=1}^n |Ba_j-Cb_j|^{2}=B(AB-|C|^2)$$

and having assumed $B>0$; this means $AB-|C|^2\geq 0$, which is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

**ADD** Let's compare two different proofs of Cauchy Schwarz in $\Bbb R^n$.

**PROOF1**. We can see the Cauchy Schwarz inequality is true whenever ${\bf x}=0 $ or ${\bf{y}}=0$, so discard those. Let ${\bf x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$  and ${\bf y }=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, so that $${\bf x}\cdot {\bf y}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$

We wish to show that $$|{\bf x}\cdot {\bf y}|\leq ||{\bf x}||\cdot ||{\bf y}||$$

Define $$X_i=\frac{x_i}{||{\bf x}||}$$

$$Y_i=\frac{y_i}{||{\bf y}||}$$

Because for any $x,y$ $$(x-y)^2\geq 0$$ we have that $$x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$$ Using this with $X_i,Y_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ we have that $$X_i^2 + Y_i^2 \geqslant 2{X_i}{Y_i}$$

and summing up through $1,\dots,n$ gives $$\eqalign{
  & \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {y_i^2} }}{{||{\bf{y}}|{|^2}}} + \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {x_i^2} }}{{||{\bf{x}}|{|^2}}} \geqslant 2\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}{y_i}} }}{{||{\bf{x}}|| \cdot ||{\bf{y}}||}}  \cr 
  & \frac{{||{\bf{y}}|{|^2}}}{{||{\bf{y}}|{|^2}}} + \frac{{||{\bf{x}}|{|^2}}}{{||{\bf{x}}|{|^2}}} \geqslant 2\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}{y_i}} }}{{||{\bf{x}}|| \cdot ||{\bf{y}}||}}  \cr 
  & 2 \geqslant 2\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}{y_i}} }}{{||{\bf{x}}|| \cdot ||{\bf{y}}||}}  \cr 
  & ||{\bf{x}}|| \cdot ||{\bf{y}}|| \geqslant \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}{y_i}}  \cr} $$

**NOTE** How may we add the absolute value signs to conclude?

**PROOF2**

We can see the Cauchy Schwarz inequality is true whenever ${\bf x}=0 $ or ${\bf{y}}=0$, or $y=\lambda x$ for some scalar. Thus, discard those hypotheses. Then consider the polynomial (here $\cdot$ is inner product) $$\displaylines{
  P(\lambda ) = \left\| {{\bf x} - \lambda {\bf{y}}} \right\|^2 \cr 
   = ( {\bf x}  - \lambda {\bf{y}})\cdot({\bf x} - \lambda {\bf{y}}) \cr 
   = {\left\| {\bf x} \right\|^2} - 2\lambda {\bf x} \cdot {\bf{y}} + {\lambda ^2}{\left\| {\bf{y}} \right\|^2} \cr} $$

Since ${\bf x}\neq \lambda{\bf y}$ for any $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, $P(\lambda)>0$ for each $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. It follows the discriminant is *negative*, that is  $$\Delta  = b^2-4ac={\left( {-2\left( {{\bf x} \cdot y} \right)} \right)^2} - 4{\left\| {\bf x} \right\|^2}{\left\| {\bf{y}} \right\|^2} <0$$ so that $$\displaylines{
  {\left( {{\bf x}\cdot {\bf{y}}} \right)^2} <{\left\| {\bf x} \right\|^2}{\left\| {\bf{y}} \right\|^2} \cr 
  \left| {{\bf x} \cdot {\bf{y}}} \right| <\left\| {\bf x}\right\| \cdot \left\| {\bf{y}} \right\| \cr} $$ which is Cauchy Schwarz, with equaliy if and only if ${\bf x}=\lambda {\bf y}$ for some $0\neq \lambda \in\Bbb R$ or either vector is null.

---

One proof shows the Cauchy Schwarz inequality is a direct consequence of the known fact that $x^2\geq 0$ for each real $x$. The other is shorter and sweeter, and uses the fact that a norm is always nonnegative, and properties of the inner product of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, plus that fact that a polynomial in $\Bbb R$ with no real roots must have negative discriminant.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was hoping for. I see that it works and I understand the proof, but I wanted to know if there was an idea behind choosing such a sum. Seems like its just one of those "you see it or you don't" kind of proofs.

Comment: @BryanUrizar Sadly, some proofs work like that. They are good because they **work**. Some people like to say there is a "trick" to it. But really, if you understand why $(1)$ is true, then you understand the proof. You might think "Well, I wouldn't have thought of that in a million years!", but with some time you'll see how we can pull of "tricks" to prove stuff.

Comment: @BryanUrizar The reason for this choice is that given the series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ there's really only a few things you can do. Writing the value of the sum is one of the ones that comes naturally, and then showing the equalities is basically just some tedium.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff That's exactly what I was thinking. I guess I hope I'll reach that level someday. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Arkasmis Thanks!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Note that your first proof requires some care, because it works in $\Bbb R^n$, whereas Rudin's proof works also for $\Bbb C$; thus, $x^2 > 0$ is not a foregone conclusion. You just have to make sure to note that $(\Im z)^2 = (\Im \bar{z})^2 > 0$; alternatively, note the "equivalence" between $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Arkamis I clearly wrote "Let's compare two different proofs of Cauchy Schwarz in $\Bbb R^n$." so I guess it is clear we're not talking about $\Bbb C$ where the inner product has another form. But yeah, that does it.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I know -- I just didn't want it to get lost that the book does it in $\Bbb C$. Some people are sticklers. I knew a professor that even went so far as to accuse a student of cheating because he called it Cauchy-Schwarz, whereas the book refers to it as "Schwarz's inequality". My comment is for the OP's benefit. ;)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thanks for those two very nice proofs. It's amazing how people see these things. Just to answer your note: I get the absolute value by considering $-\bf{x}$ in the final inequality.

Comment: @BryanUrizar You're welcome. You'll see them too with time. And yes, that is perfect.

Comment: I've been wondering where $\sum_{j=1}^n |Ba_j-Cb_j|^{2}$ came from **forever**! I didn't realize it was a simple as "it is always non negative". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Questions about how a mathematician came to realize a particular starting point, I think is very valuable, under-appreciated, and answers like "because it works" are unhelpful.  Tautologically, the person who first found this method, whomever it was, didn't know that it works until first trying it.  It's just more honest to confess "I don't know how anyone first realized this."

But let's try to build it from scratch -- I think it's a useful and interesting exercise.

---

For one thing, I think we should start by restricting attention to the real numbers, and the case where $n=2$.  Since the number of parameters is now small, let's just talk about $(w^2+x^2)(y^2+z^2)$ as the right-hand side of the inequality.  Observe that this is the same as $w^2y^2+w^2z^2+x^2y^2+x^2z^2$.

Relating this to $(wy+xz)^2 = w^2y^2+2wxyz+x^2z^2$, it's obvious that the inequality follows if we can show $2wxyz \le w^2z^2+x^2y^2$.  We could move the left side to the right side, factor, and so on -- but this method may not generalize to a larger $n$.

---

In fact it may be important to see one larger $n$, so that we don't get tempted by any steps which are only valid for $n=2$.  For $n=3$

$$ \begin{aligned}(a^2+b^2+c^2)(d^2+e^2+f^2) = &a^2d^2+a^2e^2+a^2f^2+\\
&b^2d^2+b^2e^2+b^2f^2+\\
&c^2d^2+c^2e^2+c^2f^2\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
(ad+be+cf)^2 = & a^2d^2 + 2abde + 2acdf + \\
&+ b^2e^2 + 2bcef \\
&+ c^2f^2
\end{aligned}$$

It's easy enough to work out the distribution with basic algebra.  Note that I've grouped terms so as to show a pattern that you could realize after you've worked out the details.  The products of squares are again present, $a^2d^2+b^2e^2+c^2f^2$.  And we get terms with four variables again.  In general this will always happen, even for larger $n$.  And as always, we can remove the shared terms and focus on proving the inequality on what remains.  In this case we want

$$2(abde+acdf+bcef) \le a^2e^2+a^2f^2+b^2d^2+b^2f^2+c^2d^2+c^2e^2$$

But this shows that in fact the method we looked at before, indeed works again here.  We have three terms on the left with a factor of 2 on each.  Move them over, group appropriately, factor, and you get

$$ 0\le (ad-be)^2+(ad-cf)^2+(be-cf)^2 $$

which is clearly true.  In fact we can continue in the same way for all $n$, and get a more intuitive and natural proof.

But of course, that was not the question -- the question is, how did Rudin or anyone else, come about this mysterious move?

(Sorry this is somewhat rambly, but that's how it often goes when you're trying to come up with something "new".)

---

Here's a different perspective:  The thing we want is actually the same thing as

$$C^2 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^2 \right) B$$

Also this is equivalent to

$$ 0 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B|a_i|^2\right) - C^2 $$

Factoring, in some sense, seems like clearly a valuable thing.  But how?

The left looks almost like a perfect square except missing a square on $B$.  Let's multiply throughout by $B$.

$$ 0 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B^2|a_i|^2\right)-BC^2 $$

Ok, maybe an improvement, but now the other term isn't a perfect square.  Well, it starts to look closer if we express that $B$ as a sum.

$$ 0 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B^2|a_i|^2\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2C^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (B^2|a_i|^2 - |b_i|^2C^2) $$

This looks a ton like a difference of squares, but that's actually kinda bad, because the factorization of a difference of squares isn't guaranteed to be nonnegative.  We want this to be a square of a sum.  It's not crazy to try to re-express $-|b_i|^2C^2$ as $-2|b_i|^2C^2+|b_i|^2C^2$ and hope that this left term becomes like a cross-term.  It almost does, but not quite.

But if we first distribute the summation again, it will give us a better hint as to what the manipulation should be.

$$ \begin{aligned}
0 \le & \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B^2 |a_i|^2\right) - \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2C^2 \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B^2|a_i|^2\right) - 2\sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2C^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2 C^2 
\end{aligned}$$

Now on the middle terms we can expand one $C$ (the cross-terms should have one $C$ anyway, so getting rid of one could be a good thing).

$$ \begin{aligned}
0 \le & \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B^2|a_i|^2\right) - 2BC\sum_{i=1}^n|a_ib_i| + \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2 C^2 \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^n \left( B^2|a_i|^2 - 2BC|a_ib_i| + |b_i|C^2\right) \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^n (B|a_i|-C|b_i|)^2
\end{aligned}$$

And there it is, finally we have a plausible story of where that $\sum(B|a_i|-C|b_i|)^2$ came from.

---

I'm sure Rudin preferred the way he presented the proof because it's fast and clean, compared to exposing all the logic and psychology of the process.  But personally I hate that way of presenting a proof, especially if it's to a first-time student.  In an intro class, no object should *ever* come out of nowhere.